# transform one item in a listbox to another listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

i have the following code of moving one item from (lb1) to another (lb2) i have seen lots of examples about it but when i do it it does not add any items to lb2
i'm working with visual studio and reading from a database (if it makes any difference).what could be wrong?

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(lb1.SelectedItem != null)
        {   
            // add the item to the lb2 
            lb2.Items.Add(lb1.SelectedItem);

            // remove the item from the lb1
            lb1.Items.Remove(lb1.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "It's not working" is not sufficient to descibe a problem or exception.

Comment: i edited it i hope this is ok